# glm combine rotation and translation

Tags: opengl, 3d, transform, glm-math

I have an object which I first want to rotate (about its own center) then translate it to some point. I have a glm::quat that holds the rotation and a glm::vec3 that holds the point to which it needs to be translated.

```
glm::vec3 position;
glm::quat orientation;
glm::mat4 modelmatrix; <-- want to combine them both in here

modelmatrix = glm::translate(glm::toMat4(orientation),position);
```

Then at my render function, I do.

```
pvm = projectionMatrix*viewMatrix*modelmatrix;
glUniformMatrix4fv(pvmMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(pvm));
```

..and render...

Unfortunately, the object just orbits around the origin when I apply a rotation (the farther the "position" from the origin, the larger the orbit).

When I apply for only the position it translates fine. When I apply only the rotation it stays at the origin and rotates about its center (as expected). So why does it go weird when I apply them both? Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because you're applying them in the wrong order. By doing `glm::translate(glm::toMat4(orientation),position)`, you are doing the equivalent of this:

```
glm::mat4 rot = glm::toMat4(orientation);
glm::mat4 trans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), position);
glm::mat4 final = rot * trans;
```

Note that the translation is on the right side of the matrix, not the left. This means that the translation happens *first*, then the rotation happens *relative to the translation*. So rotation happens in the space after translation.

You want the rotation to happen *first*. So reverse the order of the matrix multiplication.

Comment: I was under the impression that glm::translate applies the translation to the 1st argument of the function. Thank you.

Comment: @Jubei: It *does* apply the translation to the matrix. It right-multiplies it. That means the translation occurs *first*, when you want the rotation to happen first.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I've been stuck on this a while today, but even though I figured out what I was doing wrong I simply couldn't find any confirmation that this is how the functions are supposed to work.

Comment: Why are the functions backwards like this? I think the intuitive meaning would be for the matrix you passed in to have the translation applied *afterwards*. Is there a specific reason for this choice?